# Replacing a char in a string is not working for me

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSString chars` , which i build in some way , than i have to replace a char of it , so i do it with this :

```
[chars stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num] withString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1]];
```

if i print  :

```
NSLog(@"CHAR:%@ and look for:%@ replace with:%@",chars,[self convertDecimalToChar:num],[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1]);
```

I can see :`U U V`  , so he has to replace U with V , but it still U ..

Wht could i miss here ?
THanks .

Comment: Do you assign the returned value of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` to `char`? The methods `stringBy...` will return a new `NSString` not change the existing string because if it is inmutable.

Comment: Use "stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:" instead.
Follow this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_120

Comment: Thanks both ! i was thinking it changes my string . so whats better to assign that the my string or use the other method you gave me ?

Comment: Actually i dont know the range ...so how should i act ?

Comment: The `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString` also return a new string, so you should assign it to an other `NSString` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the return value to a `NSString`:

```
NSString *replaced = [chars stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num] withString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1]];

NSLog(@"CHAR:%@ and look for:%@ replace with:%@ results in %@",chars,[self convertDecimalToChar:num],[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1], replaced);
```

In case of a [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) use [`replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a)

```
[chat replaceCharactersInRange:[self convertDecimalToChar:num]withString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1];
```

or [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) if you need more options, like case insensitive replace:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [char length]);
[char replaceOccurrencesOfString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num] withString:[self convertDecimalToChar:num+1] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:range];
```

You might want to use the search option `NSLiteralSearch` if you also want to replace to match the case of the given string.

Comment: Changed my answer to also include the replace method for `NSMutableString`, but you should really have found this one in the documentation your self.